# I want to limit amount of pagination numbers in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-router, react-hooks

I want to limit the amount of pagination! I am taking page amount numbers from the backend using useEffect and Axios! after looping those numbers and displaying them in JSX! but I cannot limit that numbers! Could you help me? Here is the code...

```
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState();
```

here I am using use params to take pagenumlink from URL!

```
const params = useParams();
  // console.log(params);
let pageNumLink = params.page;
```

after I am using useEffect to take page numbers from the backend!

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBlogs = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/article/list/${pageNumLink}`
        );
        setArticleData(res.data.articles);
        setPageNumber(res.data.pageCount);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchBlogs();
  }, [pageNumLink]);
```

after I am looping pagenumber for it!

```
  var pagesArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= pageNumber; i++) {
    pagesArray.push(<Link to={`/articles/${i}`}>{i}</Link>);
  }
```

and after putting that in JSX:

```
<div>
   {pagesArray}
</div>
```

result is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9!! so how can I limit this and have this result! 1 2 3 ... 9! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Set a limit and once this is reached exit out of the loop. For the last page just pop it out of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Get the current page and the total number of pages. Say your current page is 1 and the total is 9. Save the current page number and total number of pages in a variable.

If the logic is that the current page (1), the next two pages (2, 3), and the final page (9) should appear, you will need to create component to give you:

(pageNumber, pageNumber + 2, pageNumber + 3 ... totalPages)

I don't think you need a loop or map for this, as you know the output beforehand. Just do something like:

```
<Link to={`/articles/${i}`}>{pageNumber}</Link>
<Link to={`/articles/${i}`}>{pageNumber + 2}</Link>
<Link to={`/articles/${i}`}>{pageNumber + 3}</Link>
... <Link to={`/articles/${i}`}>{totalPages}</Link>
```

Case to handle: current page is the amount of total pages, or within 2 of the total. (Ex. pages 7, 8, 9). You will not want to show the ...9 in this case. Add a conditional to account for this.

```
<Link to={`/articles/${pageNumber}`}>{pageNumber}</Link>
<Link to={`/articles/${pageNumber + 2}`}>{pageNumber + 2}</Link>
<Link to={`/articles/${pageNumber + 3}`}>{pageNumber + 3}</Link>
if(currentPage <== totalPages - 2) {
   ... <Link to={`/articles/${totalPages}`}>{totalPages}</Link>
}
```

Obviously the above would need whatever formatting/styling you're using.